# Node.js mongoose array memory leak

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passenger

My app crash after x time, a mongo db have collection with ~150000 documents.

My app  : nginx - phusion-passenger - node.js

In this app, have a function to find docs with verif date is (date.now - 4h) and update docs returned.

But the app crash with error :

```
App 31178 stderr: FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
App 31178 stdout: 
App 31178 stdout: <--- Last few GCs --->
App 31178 stdout: 
App 31178 stdout: 11293603 ms: Scavenge 1397.0 (1458.1) -> 1397.0 (1458.1) MB, 0.5 / 0 ms (+ 3.0 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure] [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].
App 31178 stdout: 11294683 ms: Mark-sweep 1397.0 (1458.1) -> 1396.9 (1458.1) MB, 1079.7 / 0 ms (+ 4.1 ms in 2 steps since start of marking, biggest step 3.0 ms) [last resort gc].
App 31178 stdout: 11295754 ms: Mark-sweep 1396.9 (1458.1) -> 1396.8 (1458.1) MB, 1071.1 / 0 ms [last resort gc].
App 31178 stdout: 
App 31178 stdout: 
App 31178 stdout: <--- JS stacktrace --->
App 31178 stdout: 
App 31178 stdout: ==== JS stack trace =========================================
App 31178 stdout: 
App 31178 stdout: Security context: 0x1b07beae3ac1 <JS Object>
App 31178 stdout:     1: new constructor(aka MongooseDocumentArray) [/var/www/****/code/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/documentarray.js:~23] [pc=0x32b101f3b00b] (this=0x1fe592fffc09 <a MongooseDocumentArray with map 0x7832d03a399>,values=0x1fe592fffbe9 <JS Array[0]>,path=0x1fe592ff2761 <String[11]: oldpricearr>,doc=0x1fe592fffb91 <a model with map 0x7832d0386b9>)
App 31178 stdout:     3: /* anonymous */ [/var/www/****/code/nod...
App 31178 stdout: 
[ 2016-02-13 16:59:37.0099 31143/7f907f278700 age/Cor/App/Poo/AnalyticsCollection.cpp:105 ]: Process (pid=31178, group=/var/www/****/code/public) no longer exists! Detaching it from the pool.
[ 2016-02-13 16:59:37.0100 31143/7f907f278700 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:794 ]: Checking whether to disconnect long-running connections for process 31178, application /var/www/****/code/public
```

This key `<String[11]: oldpricearr>` is an array:

`[{price: 5445, date: isodate},{price: 5468, date: isodate},{price: 45121, date: isodate},{price: 4785 date: isodate}, ect..];`

Is this docs corrupted? Or the array in this docs is too big for push new element?
How to find the problem?

Comment: The biggest key is to use `lean()` queries whenever you don't actually need full Mongoose doc instances. Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575769/way-to-lower-memory-usage-by-mongoose-when-doing-query

Comment: thanks, I'm going to try .lean(), but I think is in update docs the problem.